# apache rewrite mod enabled but getting errors

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite

```
Invalid command 'RewriteEngine', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
Invalid command 'RewriteCond', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
```

i ran `a2enmod rewrite`, it says "mod already enabled"

Now i get

```
RewriteEngine not allowed here
```

Answer (score 3):

If you have your rules in a `.htaccess` file, then the reason for the *not allowed here* is almost certainly the `AllowOverride` setting is too restrictive.  Generally it is set by default to allow very little.  In your site's configuration in */etc/apache2/sites-available/foobar*, add this, adjusting the directory path of course:

```
<Directory /var/www/mydirectory>
    AllowOverride +FileInfo
</Directory>
```

Answer (score 0):

Restart Apache, perhaps?  If you're trying to do this in a `.htaccess` file.  Certainly, "Invalid command 'RewriteEngine'" indicates that `mod_rewrite` is not enabled, regardless of what `a2enmod` might say on the matter.  Perhaps make sure that `/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/rewrite.load` has sensible-looking contents, in case something went a bit spare in there.

Comment: now i am getting

RewriteEngine not allowed here

Comment: What is the difference between "Now" and "Then"?  If you *are* doing this in a htaccess, yes, you don't use RewriteEngine On, you just define your rewrite rules.